# spliting large query string in acess

Tags: c#, .net, sql, t-sql

I had a long query in access and trying to make it into multiple lines so that i can check them during my debugging and I tried the steps which I found through google and its failing with the information shown below.

```
    public DataSet showallCompanyPaymentbyjobcode(int jobpk ,int confirmquotationpk)
        {

            string query=SELECT companypaymentmastertable.paymentpk, companypaymentmastertable.cmpinvoice, companypaymentmastertable.jobcode, companypaymentmastertable.customercode, confirmquotationmastertable.quotationcode, companypaymentmastertable.customerName, companypaymentmastertable.ischeque, companypaymentmastertable.isCash, companypaymentmastertable.amount, companypaymentmastertable.chequenumber, companypaymentmastertable.bankname, companypaymentmastertable.chequedate, companypaymentmastertable.chequereleasedate, companypaymentmastertable.companypaymentdate
FROM confirmquotationmastertable INNER JOIN companypaymentmastertable ON confirmquotationmastertable.confirmpk=companypaymentmastertable.confirmpk
WHERE (((companypaymentmastertable.confirmpk)=[?]) AND ((companypaymentmastertable.jobpk)=15));


                               OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, Program.ConnStr);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                dAdapter.Fill(ds, "tblpayview");

                if (ds.Tables.Count <= 0)
                {
                    ds = null;    
                }

                return ds;

            }
```

in another class i called it

```
 public void fillpaymenttable()
        {
            DataSet ds= new DataSet();
            ds= companytransaction.showallCompanyPaymentbyjobcode(cmbjobcode.SelectedValue,cmbQuotationcode.SelectedValue);

             tblpaymentview.DataSource = ds.Tables["tblpayview"].DefaultView;

                if (ds.Tables.Count <= 0)
                {
                    lblstatus.Text = "No Payment Details Present";
                    clearcontrols();
                }

            }
```

Is there any way to split the query and whether this function work if dataset called like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be more efficient than using a stringbuilder, because the string concatenation will be performed at compile time, not at run time:

```
string query="SELECT companypaymentmastertable.paymentpk, companypaymentmastertable.cmpinvoice, "
 + "companypaymentmastertable.jobcode, companypaymentmastertable.customercode, "
 + "confirmquotationmastertable.quotationcode, companypaymentmastertable.customerName, "
 + "companypaymentmastertable.ischeque, companypaymentmastertable.isCash, companypaymentmastertable.amount, "
 + "companypaymentmastertable.chequenumber, companypaymentmastertable.bankname, companypaymentmastertable.chequedate, "
 + "companypaymentmastertable.chequereleasedate, companypaymentmastertable.companypaymentdate "
 + "FROM confirmquotationmastertable INNER JOIN companypaymentmastertable ON "
 + "confirmquotationmastertable.confirmpk=companypaymentmastertable.confirmpk "
 + "WHERE (((companypaymentmastertable.confirmpk)=[?]) AND ((companypaymentmastertable.jobpk)=15));"
```

Alternatively, you could use a "verbatim string":

```
    string query= @"SELECT companypaymentmastertable.paymentpk, companypaymentmastertable.cmpinvoice, 
companypaymentmastertable.jobcode, companypaymentmastertable.customercode, 
confirmquotationmastertable.quotationcode, companypaymentmastertable.customerName, 
companypaymentmastertable.ischeque, companypaymentmastertable.isCash, companypaymentmastertable.amount, 
companypaymentmastertable.chequenumber, companypaymentmastertable.bankname, companypaymentmastertable.chequedate, 
companypaymentmastertable.chequereleasedate, companypaymentmastertable.companypaymentdate    
FROM confirmquotationmastertable 
INNER JOIN companypaymentmastertable ON confirmquotationmastertable.confirmpk=companypaymentmastertable.confirmpk    
WHERE (((companypaymentmastertable.confirmpk)=[?]) AND ((companypaymentmastertable.jobpk)=15));";
```

Comment: +1 phoog.  Too many people think that StringBuilder is always better than string concatenation.

Comment: Yeah, me included really. I stand corrected :). It's a close call though :P source: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/10/c-string-compares-and-concatenations.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you're just wanting to actually split the code up into separate lines, use a `StringBuilder`? Note that this wouldn't be the case if you were passing parameters to the query as you'd be vulnerable to SQL injections

```
var query = new StringBuilder();

query.Append("SELECT companypaymentmastertable.paymentpk, companypaymentmastertable.cmpinvoice, ");
query.Append("companypaymentmastertable.jobcode, companypaymentmastertable.customercode, ");
query.Append("confirmquotationmastertable.quotationcode, companypaymentmastertable.customerName, ");
query.Append("companypaymentmastertable.ischeque, companypaymentmastertable.isCash, ");
query.Append("companypaymentmastertable.amount, companypaymentmastertable.chequenumber, ");
query.Append("companypaymentmastertable.bankname, companypaymentmastertable.chequedate, ");
query.Append(" companypaymentmastertable.chequereleasedate, companypaymentmastertable.companypaymentdate ");
query.Append("FROM confirmquotationmastertable INNER JOIN companypaymentmastertable ");
query.Append("ON confirmquotationmastertable.confirmpk=companypaymentmastertable.confirmpk ");
query.Append("WHERE (((companypaymentmastertable.confirmpk)=[?]) ");
query.Append("AND ((companypaymentmastertable.jobpk)=15))");
```

Comment: query.Append("WHERE (((companypaymentmastertable.confirmpk)=[?]) ");
query.Append("AND ((companypaymentmastertable.jobpk)=15))");                             iwill get parameters from user here using oledbcmnd.parameter .adwithvalue();

Comment: Okay that's fine, just change [?] to be your parameter name and the 15 to be your other parameter name, then you can do AddWithValue on those parameters.

Comment: @sreenathsreenath note that using stringbuilder introduces a lot of unneccessary overhead here.  StringBuilder is mostly useful for loops and other situations where the components of the string are determined at run time.

Comment: Are you sure? I was going to just do basic string manipulation, but I thought it was worse on performance?

Comment: Actually you're right, although the difference isn't *too* great http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/10/c-string-compares-and-concatenations.aspx

Comment: @mattytommo note that the first example in my answer doesn't call concat, either.  *The compiler folds the constants!*  The article you linked to doesn't mention that.  Constant folding is required by the language specification.  As a result `string s = "this" + " " + "is" + " " + "a" + " " + "string";` compiles to the same code as `string s = "this is a string";`.

Comment: @phoog Wow that's pretty cool, I didn't know that :). Thanks for that!